# Flex - Set Editable propertie programmatically for a GridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript

Is it possible to dynamically change the property "Editable" of a GridColumn regarding the value of an another Column.
Once I have filled my dataProvider I would like to loop ont he dataGrid rows, but I can't find how to it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
editable="{if (data['Type']=='foo'){return true;} else {return false;}}"
```

but build failed.

How about to use itemRenderer?

```
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Type" width="100" editable="false"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Name" width="100" editable="false"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Score" width="100" editable="true" rendererIsEditable="true">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                                        if (value != null && value != "") {
                                            super.data = value;
                                            if (super.data["Type"] == "foo"){
                                                somefield.editable = true;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                somefield.editable = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            <s:TextInput id="somefield" text="{data.Score}"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
```

[Run example on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/qdgm)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. In fact I use ItemEditor and/or ItemRenderer for some columns.

In my case I have

```
<s:GridColumn id="gcAmountEUR" labelFunction="amountFormat" dataField="AmountEUR" headerText="AMOUNT EUR"  width="80" itemEditor="components.gieOrderAmount">
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer textAlign="right" />
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="CurrencyCode" headerText="CURRENCY"  width="50" itemEditor="components.gieOrderCurrency"  >
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn id="gcAmount" labelFunction="amountFormat" dataField="Amount" headerText="AMOUNT" width="120" itemEditor="components.gieOrderAmount">
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer textAlign="right" />
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>
```

The datagrig has the property editable="true".

By default the column AmountEUR is Editable an the column Amount is not.
But if for a row the value of Currency is not "" so I want AmountEUR to be not Editable and Amount to be Editable. So I would like to programmatically change the property Editable of the column for each row.
So I would like to parse the datagrid to change, for each row, the property value "Editable" of AmountEUR and Amount if Currency is not Empty.

But perhaps it is not the good way to do it ?
I hope I made myself clear.

Antoine.